# colored box hyperref error for latex->dvips->ps2pdf in tex live 2019

Tags: hyperref, texlive, dvips, ps2pdf, texlive-2019

I am using tex live 2019, and I have a problem with hyperref.

The error does not happen when I use PDFLaTeX as shown in the first image.

However, when I use latex->dvips->ps2pdf, all citations and references are hidden with the colored box. (second image)

How can I solve this problem?

[image: PDFLaTeX]

[image: LaTeX->DVIPS->PS2PDF]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn, 10pt]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{stfloats}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{psfrag}
\usepackage[mathscr]{euscript}
\usepackage{acronym}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\begin{document}
   \begin{align}
       A=B
       \label{equation}
   \end{align}
This is the equation \eqref{equation}.
\end{document}
```

Above is the code I used.

I am using TexStudio. So I compiled my code by:

Tools > Commands > LaTeX

Tools > Commands > DVI->PS

Tools > Commands > PS->PDF

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]!  Please show us the code for these examples.  For example, in  the second case did you pass the `dvips` option to `hyperref`?

Comment: I have edited the question! What do you mean by "passing the dvips option to hyperref" ?

Comment: I can reproduce it (with a much smaller example), but I can't look now.

Comment: It is possible to write `\usepackage[dvips]{hyperref}` or `\usepackage[ps2pdf]{hyperref}`.  Does either of these help?  I can't reproduce your problem on my system.

Comment: If you are using `dvips` and `ps2pdf` then no need of `epstopdf` package

Comment: @AndrewSwann Neither of them helped... I still have colored boxes.

Comment: @MadyYuvi Thank you for your comment! I have removed `epstopdf` package. But the error still exists..

Comment: @UlrikeFischer you can? I just tried the above and didn't get a filled box?

Comment: can you report which ghostscript version you have, Ulrike can reproduce with gs 9.50 but I can not reproduce with an up to data texlive but gs 2.27

Comment: @DavidCarlisle My ghostcript version is "GPL Ghostscript 9.50". Is this the problem?

Comment: Try if it works if you add after hyperref `\makeatletter \def\Hy@BorderArrayPatch{} \makeatother`.

Comment: @HeWonCho that is a possibility, as it works for me, it is hard for me to debug, but that seems to be the main difference between my setup and Ulrike's

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Wow!! It works!!!!!! Thank you very much!!! :)

Answer (score 4):

**Note:** `hyperref` has been updated to detect the version of GhostScript being used by `pstopdf` and to use the appropriate code in each case. So the workaround described below is not needed (since January 2020 release of `hyperref`).

---

Ulrike in chat provided a simpler test case

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\url{www.abc.de}
\end{document}
```

which for me (with gs 9.27) produces

[image]

but with 9.50 produces

[image]

It turns out GhostScript changed its interpretation of the border specification at 9.50

http://git.ghostscript.com/?p=ghostpdl.git;a=commitdiff;h=90bdf83d696562e4136b8f565cac06cc32b161ae

In the comments under the question Ulrike showed how to disable the code in hyperref but that makes things work in 9.50 but fail in any older release, the code below should I hope work with either way, it inserts a test on the gs release number that is implemented in PostScript so deferred until you run ps2pdf on the PostScript generated by dvips.

If anyone who tries this comments whether it works or doesn't work and which version of gs they have, that would be useful, thanks!

Save the code below as `hdvips.def` in the same folder as the test file (whole file provided as it is inconvenient to patch this)

```
%%
%% This is file `hdvips.def',
%% generated with the docstrip utility.
%%
%% The original source files were:
%%
%% hyperref.dtx  (with options: `dvips')
%% 
%% File: hyperref.dtx Copyright 1995-2001 Sebastian Rahtz,
%% with portions written by David Carlisle and Heiko Oberdiek,
%% 2001-2012 Heiko Oberdiek.
%% 2016-2019 Oberdiek Package Suport Group
%% 2019 LaTeX3 Project
%%      https://github.com/latex3/hyperref/issues
%%
%% This file is part of the `Hyperref Bundle'.
%% -------------------------------------------
%%
%% This work may be distributed and/or modified under the
%% conditions of the LaTeX Project Public License, either version 1.3
%% of this license or (at your option) any later version.
%% The latest version of this license is in
%%   http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt
%% and version 1.3 or later is part of all distributions of LaTeX
%% version 2005/12/01 or later.
%%
%% This work has the LPPL maintenance status `maintained'.
%%
%% The Current Maintainer of this work is the LaTeX3 Project.
%%
%% The list of all files belonging to the `Hyperref Bundle' is
%% given in the file `manifest.txt'.
%%
\ProvidesFile{hdvips.def}
  [2019/11/10 v7.00c %
  Hyperref driver for dvips + gs test]
\Hy@VersionCheck{hdvips.def}
\providecommand*{\XR@ext}{pdf}
\let\Hy@raisedlink\@empty
\def\literalps@out#1{\special{ps:SDict begin #1 end}}%
\def\headerps@out#1{\special{! #1}}%
\input{pdfmark.def}%
\ifx\@pdfproducer\relax
  \def\@pdfproducer{dvips + Distiller}%
\fi
\providecommand*\@pdfborder{0 0 1}
\providecommand*\@pdfborderstyle{}
\providecommand*\@pdfview{XYZ}
\providecommand*\@pdfviewparams{ H.V}
\def\Hy@BorderArrayPatch{BorderArrayPatch}
\g@addto@macro\Hy@FirstPageHook{%
  \headerps@out{%
    /DvipsToPDF{72.27 mul Resolution div} def%
    /PDFToDvips{72.27 div Resolution mul} def%
    /BPToDvips{72 div Resolution mul}def
    %%%%%
    %%%%%
    %%%%% START CHANGE
    %if  using gs and release < 9.50 patch, otherwise make this a no-op
    product (Ghostscript) search {pop pop pop  revision 950 lt } {pop false} ifelse
    {
    /BorderArrayPatch{%
      [exch{%
        dup dup type/integertype eq exch type/realtype eq or%
        {BPToDvips}if%
      }forall]%
    }def
    }{
    /BorderArrayPatch{} def
    }
    ifelse
   % end of gs version test
   %%%
   %%% END
   %%%
    /HyperBorder {1 PDFToDvips} def%
    /H.V {pdf@hoff pdf@voff null} def%
    /H.B {/Rect[pdf@llx pdf@lly pdf@urx pdf@ury]} def%
    /H.S {%
      currentpoint %
      HyperBorder add /pdf@lly exch def %
      dup DvipsToPDF 72 add /pdf@hoff exch def %
      HyperBorder sub /pdf@llx exch def%
    } def%
    /H.L {%
      2 sub dup%
      /HyperBasePt exch def %
      PDFToDvips /HyperBaseDvips exch def %
      currentpoint %
      HyperBaseDvips sub /pdf@ury exch def%
      /pdf@urx exch def%
    } def%
    /H.A {%
      H.L %
      currentpoint exch pop %
      vsize 72 sub exch DvipsToPDF %
      HyperBasePt sub % baseline skip
      sub /pdf@voff exch def%
    } def%
    /H.R {%
      currentpoint %
      HyperBorder sub /pdf@ury exch def %
      HyperBorder add /pdf@urx exch def %
      currentpoint exch pop vsize 72 sub %
      exch DvipsToPDF sub /pdf@voff exch def%
    } def%
  }%
}
\AtBeginShipoutFirst{%
  \ifHy@setpagesize
    \begingroup
      \@ifundefined{stockwidth}{%
        \ifdim\paperwidth>\z@
          \ifdim\paperheight>\z@
            \special{papersize=\the\paperwidth,\the\paperheight}%
          \fi
        \fi
      }{%
        \ifdim\stockwidth>\z@
          \ifdim\stockheight>\z@
            \special{papersize=\the\stockwidth,\the\stockheight}%
          \fi
        \fi
      }%
    \endgroup
  \fi
  \Hy@DisableOption{setpagesize}%
}
\def\setpdflinkmargin#1{%
  \begingroup
    \setlength{\dimen@}{#1}%
    \literalps@out{%
      /HyperBorder{\strip@pt\dimen@\space PDFToDvips}def%
    }%
  \endgroup
}
\endinput
%%
%% End of file `hdvips.def'.
```

Comment: Thus, it is a long-standing incompatibility of GS with Distiller that has been fixed eventually. Thanks!

Comment: The issue has been resolved with the latest hyperref update.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I'll add a note to the answer (feel free to edit answers if we fix things:-)

Comment: Glad to hear...