# Hyperref clickable area too small for auto- and supercites

Tags: biblatex, hyperref

My problem is, when using `\autocite{}` or `\supercite` with hyperref, the linking area is very small, its not touching the superscript anywhere, and in the middle of the line, not on the height of the superscript.
I am using BibLaTeX.

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage[autocite=superscript,
    backend=biber,
    hyperref=true,
    url=false,
    isbn=false,
    doi=false,
    maxnames=4]{biblatex}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}

\addbibresource{Wald.bib}


\begin{document}
Text\autocite{Wald}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

my dummy Wald.bib file:

```
@Article{Wald,
  author  = {Walter Ewald},
  title   = {Walten im Wald},
  journal = {Waldwerke},
  year    = {1208},
  date    = {1208-12-12},
}

@Comment{jabref-meta: databaseType:biblatex;}
```

I am currently using Windows 10, MiKTeX 2.9.7250 64-bit, pdfTeX Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20.
Normal quick compile is pdfTeX -> Biber -> 2x pdfTeX -> divps -> ps2pdf, but the problem is still there when only using pdftex.
In the following picture, the clickable area is highlighted blue (it is the same with colorlinks=false, so I didnt include a picture for that)

[image: Output with highlighted link area.]

Comment: Hello, place your minimum example and what you are compiling with, if you want you can add an image to understand more about it, you don't need to upload the PDF

Comment: The MWE in this case should just reproduce the problematic output in the PDF with as little code as possible. It is not an issue that you can't upload a PDF, we just need code that reproduces what you are complaining about.

Comment: Mhhh, the link I get from the MWE appears to be alright (its area is basically a small box around the superscript 1). Can you please tell us how you compile your document (pdfLaTeX, LuaLaTeX, XeLaTeX, LaTeX to DVI) and a bit more about your system (what OS, MikTeX or TeX live, what versions)? If you load `hyperref` just with `\usepackage{hyperref}` instead of `\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}` does the size of the link box look right? Can you include a screenshot of the PDF in the question (ideally one with `\usepackage{hyperref}` and one with `\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}`)?

Comment: Does the problem really also occur if you compile with pdfLaTeX (and *not* with dvips and ps2pdf)? Somehow the sequence pdfTeX -> divps -> ps2pdf doesn't make sense, since pdfTeX would usually produce PDFs, but dvips -> ps2pdf takes a DVI and turns it into a PS and then PDF. So if there was a DVI, the PDF produced by pdfTeX is overwritten by the DVI-produced PDF. I have a hunch this might be the same issue as https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/524044/35864

Comment: Mhhh, turns out it is not the same issue as https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/524044/35864. There is a shorter MWE at https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/53242241#53242241

Comment: funnily enough I cant use only pdfLaTeX on my main document anymore (the MWE still works), it gives me `epstopdf-base.sty` not found after starting MikTeX automatically. Something similar happened to me when implementing biber, which I solved by manually placing the exe and referencing the path in TeXmaker. No idea about this though. I switched to Latex -> biber -> 2x Latex -> divps -> ps2pdf.

Comment: To solve your miktex problem: Open the miktex console, update the package list and then install the missing packages (quite a number of packages which where previously in the oberdiek package have been put in separate packages).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that  `\textsuperscript` sets `\baselineskip` to 0pt (`\z@`):

```
\def\@textsuperscript#1{%
  {\m@th\ensuremath{^{\mbox{\fontsize\sf@size\z@#1}}}}}
```

On the other side `\hyper@linkend` uses `\baselineskip`:

```
\def\hyper@linkend{%
  \literalps@out{\strip@pt@and@otherjunk\baselineskip\space H.L}%
```

Setting `\baselineskip` to a positive value e.g. `\textsuperscript` resolves the problem:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage[autocite=superscript]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}


\begin{document}
Text\autocite{doody}

\makeatletter
\def\@textsuperscript#1{%
  {\m@th\ensuremath{^{\mbox{\fontsize\sf@size\sf@size#1}}}}}
\makeatother  

Text\autocite{doody}
\end{document}
```

[image]

But the main question is where this should done at best. See also https://github.com/latex3/hyperref/issues/115